# Saving data from a form submission

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, modelform

I want to create an account registration page that links directly to an account info page and displays the account info. I'm having a hard time getting the form  to save the account info into my model and I don't know why.

models.py:

```
class Owner(models.Model):
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.fullname

""" This is a Form class and not a regular Model class """
class OwnerForm(forms.Form):
    class Meta:
        model = Owner
        fields = ['fullname', 'username', 'password', 'email']
```

views.py:

```
def register(request):
    form = OwnerForm()
    if request.POST:
        form = OwnerForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            fullname = request.POST.get('fullname', '')
            username = request.POST.get('username', '')
            password = request.POST.get('password', '')
            email = request.POST.get('email', '')
            owner_obj = Owner(fullame=fullname, username=username, password=password, email=email)
            owner_obj.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('courses/accountinfo.html')
    else:
        form = OwnerForm()
    return render_to_response('courses/register.html', {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

register.html:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% load static from staticfiles %}

{% block title %}{{ page.title }}{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<article>
        <div id="Register">
            <form action="{% url 'courses:accountinfo' %}" method="post"> {% csrf_token %}
                <p>
                    <label for="fullname">Full name:</label>
                    <input id="fullname" name="fullname" type="text">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <input id="email" name="email" type="text">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="username">Username</label>
                    <input id="username" name="username" type="text">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input id="password" name="password" type="password">
                        <span>Enter a password longer than 8 characters</span>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="confirm_password">Confirm Password</label>
                    <input id="confirm_password" name="confirm_password" type="password">
                        <span>Please confirm your password</span>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input type="submit" value="REGISTER" id="submit">
                </p>
            </form>
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
            <script src="{% static 'js/app.js' %}" charset="utf-8"></script>
      </div>
</article>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call this after checking if the `form.is_valid`, then send the redirect and let your other view handle the rest. The issue may also be with the `accountinfo` view, but you didn't post that code.

```
owner = form.save()
owner.set_password(owner.password)
owner.save()
```

Comment: I haven't really put too much thought into the accountinfo view because I figured that the register view would be the one that's important for just saving the data. Once I figured out how to save the data into my model then I'd worry about displaying it in the accountinfo page.

Comment: that little snippet of code didn't work either, I think its something to do with the html maybe

Comment: You need to make the URL point to the register view in `action=`.

Comment: ok that fixed my issue of creating a new user but now, it tries to redirect to courses/register/courses/accountinfo rather than just courses/accountinfo so I need to figure that out next. Thanks!

Comment: Add this in addition to what you have in action. `?next=/nextUrl/`

Comment: it didn't fix anything

Comment: thanks but I went a different path where I'm trying to make a confirmation page that it redirects to with the option of it displaying account information from there. now my issue is that it's not recognizing courses/register/thanks.html despite the fact that I registered it in courses/urls.py

Comment: I just had to remove the '.html' part from my redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Use the save method on the form to save the data rather than creating a model object once the form is valid. However I see that the template contains additional fields. Do you have something in the valid method?
What is the error that you are getting? are you posting to the correct url?

Comment: I'm not getting an error, it simply wasn't saving. Also I got the answer from the below post but now the url its redirecting to is incorrect.